# Magento-2 : Product not working with huge number of records selected from grid

Tags: magento2, admin, grid-serlization

I am working on custom module, I have added custom module data grid to product Add/Edit page in admin area. custom data save on product save same as like related/up-sell/cross-sell products.

When I am saving product, if selected custom module grid records with normal records it's working fine. But if I selected with 1000+ records, It was not working.

Same scenario I have checked for related products, it was working same as above.

I want solution for how to save huge numbers of data while saving products.

Any one have faced this issue, please share your ideas.

Response : **414 Request-URI Too Long : The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.**

Comment: Yes i have face same issue when i delete product with large number

Comment: Did you got any solutions or not?

Comment: Nope !! still not

Comment: I think the issue is with the module where you are trying to save the data. Seems somewhere get method is being used that is causing URL length issue.

Comment: @Suresh Chikani: Can you share phpinfo() here ?

Comment: I have set max_input_vars = 10000

Comment: I believe the reason is not max_input_vars but LimitRequestFieldSize or LimitRequestLine but it is not good to increase them. As the url may have very long string - https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/long-urls-are-rejected-by-apache-with-request-uri-too-large-error-213519617.html

Comment: Does any have a solution for this??